# AppEngine Persist object delay?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My situation is as followed:
I have a list of Session in my table. 
In my code i do a check if the last Session in the datastore has room for an aditional player.
 If not create a new Session.

It goes a little something like this:

```
public Session getEligeableSession(){
    Session session;
    session = ds.getLastSession();
    if(session.numPlayers > 3){
        newSession();
        session = ds.getLastSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

This works flawlessly on local but it doesn't on AppEngine's AppSpot.
On AppSpot i just get a filled up session back , i have to conclude from this that my code doesn't wait for the new session to get fully persisted and just get's the old session again.

Is my conclusion right? if so how would i go about solving this graciously.
Searching for this 'delay' has resulted in nothing on Google/SO which makes me believe there is no such a thing(aka it's synchronous) and there is a different fail in my code.(perhaps getting the last object from the list works differently on AppEngine)

Any and all help/advice is much appreciated.

Summary:

Session(Object) has(List) 4 Players(Object) 
**getLastSession()** retrieves the whole list from the datastore and get the last one(*size-1*).
**newSession()** creates a new Session object and persists it.

EDIT per request:

```
public List<Session> getAll(){
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    String query = "select from " + Session.class.getName();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Session> sessions = (List<Session>) pm.newQuery(query).execute();
    return sessions;
}


public Session getLastSession(){
    List<Session> sessions = getAll();
    Session session = sessions.get(sessions.size()-1);
    session.activeGame = session.numPlayers == 4 ?  true : false;
    pm.close();
    return session;
}


    public int insert(Session session){
    pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    int status = 0;
    try {
        pm.makePersistent(session);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return status;
}
```

The code seems 'Reasonable', no funny stuff happening afaik.
I'm using the master-slave option.

Comment: What's the implementation of newSession and getLastSession? Actual code is important here! And, are you using the high-replication datastore?

Comment: @Nick Johnson

I've updated my post as requested.
Forgot: NewSession is just insert(new Session);

Comment: Have you tried passing in a single persistence manager to all functions, rather than creating a new one in each?

Comment: Also, getting every session, then filtering in code _really_ isn't going to scale.

Comment: @Nick Johnson reusing old pms in the past gave me object managed exceptions, so how would i go about this. also what would be an efficient way to get the last persisted Session. Many thanks

Comment: @Nick It seems my implementation of getLastSession() got the better of me.
Using @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) on my key, AppEngine was creating lower id's in some cases and getting the last from the list would bring me a bad Session. Managing my own Keys should do the trick. Thank you Nick Johnson and Aleadam for the help. Should a remove this Question as it has no real value for anyone else, or leave it be?

Comment: @Rohan Why are you relying on key ordering? App Engine doesn't guarantee ordering, just uniqueness, but any attempt to generate your own, totally ordered, keys is likely to run into a scaling wall very quickly. Why not sort on timestamp instead?

Comment: @Nick That is a great idea, i was not aware of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess here, because I don't know how you implemented your methods, but if you're using two different instances of `PersistenceManager` in two different servlets (one to store the object, and one to retrieve it), you might be accessing two different servers immediately one after the other, not giving enough time to replicate the data throughout the datastore servers.

Take a look also at the first reply on this thread for an alternative explanation (although, depending on how `newSession();` works, it might not be the case):

http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/2b4f6ec57031f53c/fc967c034e4a113f